# Nonlinear Finite Element Discretization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

## Problem

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider stationary 1D heat conduction with Neumann boundaries:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(\kappa \frac{du}{dx}) = 0   \tag{1} $$
$$ \frac{du}{dx}|_0 = F_0   \tag{2} $$
$$ \frac{du}{dx}|_1 = F_1  \tag{3} $$

- $ x \in [0,1] $
- $ u: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $
- $ \kappa = \kappa(u(x)) $

The goal is to end up with the following formulation: $K\hat{u}=f$ , where $K=K(u)$ is the "stiffness" matrix, $\hat{u}$ is the vector of coefficients of the shape functions, and $f=f(u)$ the load vector.

## Linear case

In the linear case, $\kappa$ is constant and the (simplified) derivation looks like this:

Choose an appropriate space of ansatz functions $V : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and assume that the solution $u$ and test function $v$ can be represented as a linear combination of shape functions $N_i(x) \in V$:
$$ u = \sum_i N_i \hat{u}_i \tag{4}$$
$$ v = \sum_i N_i \tag{5}$$

The weak form follows from multiplying the heat equation by the test function and integrating over the domain:
$$ \int_0^1{v\frac{d}{dx}(\kappa \frac{du}{dx})dx} = \kappa \int_0^1{v\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}dx} = 0     \tag{6} $$

Integrate by parts to get rid of the second derivative and sneak in the boundaries:
$$ \kappa [v\frac{du}{dx}]_0^1 - \kappa\int_0^1{\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{du}{dx}dx} = 0   \tag{7} $$

Substitute $u$, $v$, and the boundaries (writing it in index notation to avoid the sums):
$$ \hat{u}_i \kappa \int_0^1{\frac{dN_i}{dx}\frac{dN_j}{dx}dx} = \kappa(N_i(1)F_1 - N_i(0)F_0)  \tag{8} $$

The FE components can be named and we're done:

- $K_{ij}:=\kappa \int_0^1{ \frac{dN_i}{dx}\frac{dN_j}{dx}dx }$
- $ f_i := \kappa(N_i(1)F_1 - N_i(0)F_0) $

## Nonlinear case

Now, $\kappa$ is a function of $u$, so it cannot be removed from the integral like in $(6)$. Subsequently, integration by parts and the substitution of $u$ and $v$ become impossible (or more complicated?). This is the step I need help with. As I already mentioned, the goal is to end up with the following form:

$$ K\hat{u} = f \tag{9} $$

The question is how to get $K$ and $f$, both of which will be functions of $u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you can just try to perform a few picard iterations. You start with some initial approximation $u^{(0)}$ and, for $k \geq 0$ you compute $u^{(k+1)}$ by solving
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(k(u^{(k)}(x)) \frac{d u^{(k+1)}}{dx} \right) =0 \quad \textrm{ + b.c}
$$

In each iteration you solve a linear problem which is not hard to formulate, as the diffusion is a known function of $x$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

In the meantime, can you give me an example when this method fails? I'm just asking because you mentioned "in this particular case".

Comment: @KelemenMáté The Picard iterations are not unconditionally convergent... Even in this case I am not sure it will converge.

Comment: Update: I tried it out and it works surprisingly well (provided the load is ramped up in small enough increments). For comparison, I gave some Newton variants a shot but they were much slower and didn't ensure convergence either.

Thanks again!